# Cross product with curl

Tags: calculus, cross-product

I'm trying to compute $u \times(\nabla \times v)$. My solution so far is below:

\begin{align*}
[u \times (\nabla \times v)]_i& = \epsilon_{ijk}u_j\epsilon_{klm}\partial_lv_m \\
& =\epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{klm}u_j\partial_lv_m \\ 
&=u_j\partial_lv_m(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}) \\ & =u_j\partial_iv_j-u_j\partial_jv_i \\
\end{align*}

I can see that the second term will give me $(u\cdot\nabla)v$, but I'm not sure what to do with the first term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you derived reads
$$u \times (\nabla \times v) = \nabla_v(u \cdot v) - (u \cdot \nabla)v$$
where the notation $\nabla_v$ is called Feynman notation and should indicate that the derivative is applied only to $v$ and not to $u$.