# How to derive Lagrangian from force considering the motion of charge particle in magnetic field?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have seen that in every derivation Starting from $L= \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2} - e\dot{x}\cdot\textbf{A}$ the equation $F= \frac{1}{2}mv^2+q(\vec{v} \times \vec{B} )$ is derived. can we derive Lagrangian  $L= \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2} - e\dot{x}\cdot\textbf{A}$? starting from force? Euler-Lagrangian equation relates force to the Lagrangian,I'm having trouble in this part $ e\dot{x}\cdot\textbf{A}$. Ho to get this part?

After substituting $B=\nabla \times \vec{A} $ and substituting identity  $\vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) = \nabla(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{A})-(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{A} $ I'm having trouble in the simplification of magnetic force.
$q(\vec{v}\times \vec{B}) = q[\vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A})] = q[\nabla(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{A})-(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{A}]$ Then how to simplify further? In the final expression of Lagrangian there is no $\nabla$ so how to get rid of this?

Comment: The first term in your force doesn't have the right dimensions. Also please be consistent in your notation - either use $q$ or $e$ throughout.

Do you know what equations relate Force to the Lagrangian?

Comment: We start from lagrangian which the defined as L=K.E -P.E. Lagrangian itself contains two forces

Comment: Is there anything unclear in my Question

Comment: Lagrangian does not contain any forces. As you have stated yourself it has the energies in there.

The think that is unclear is that your first equation has the Lorentz force ($q v\times B$) in it while you state it is the Lagrangian.

Comment: One of your identities is incorrect. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976303/cross-product-with-curl.

Comment: Identity seems correct. But my problem is with expression of Lagrangian